# PHP PDO Last Insert Id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, insert

With mysqli the last inserted id can be retrieved from a prepared-statement object, e.g.:

```
$pstm->execute();
$pstm->insert_id;
```

However with PDO this has to be done at the database level. E.g:

```
$lastId = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

I though that PDO was meant to replace mysql/mysqli, why was this design decision taken? What if two insert commands run at the same time? Because the inserted id is not scoped to a given command may it retrieve the wrong id?

Thanks

Comment: it is still connection based

Comment: I'm presuming `mysqli` just grabs it for you after running each query but PDO makes you grab it yourself.

Comment: you cant compare pdo to mysql. pdo is db independent,

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID` function is maintained at the session (database connection) level. Not at the individual prepared statement. That function returns

> the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement.

---

*"I thought that PDO was meant to replace mysql/mysqli"*

I think PDO was meant to be an *alternative* to the mysql_ and mysqli_ interfaces.  PDO is quite a bit different than either of those. For one thing, there are PDO database drivers for many databases other than MySQL (such as DB2, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, et al.).

In contrast, the mysqli_ interface specifically supports MySQL (and MariaDB versions <10.0, and possibly a few others that are MySQL compatible.)

---

*"Why was this design decision taken?"*

I think the PDO design more closely follows the pattern of the LAST_INSERT_ID function in the MySQL database itself. PDO and mysqli both provide "wrapper" functions as a convenient way of executing and retrieving the resultset from a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` statement.

I believe the developers of PDO intended it to be a lightweight and consistent interface for multiple databases. Creating a drop in replacement for mysql/mysqli was not a primary design goal.

---

*"What if two insert commands run at the same time?"*

It's not possible to run two INSERT statements "at the same time" on a single MySQL database session. They would run consecutively.

In MySQL, to retrieve the AUTO_INCREMENT value from the first INSERT statement, that first statement would need to be followed by a `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` *before* the second INSERT statement was executed.

---

*"Because the inserted id is not scoped to a given command may it retrieve the wrong id?"*

This is by design of the MySQL `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. It's not "scoped" to a particular statement. The value returned by that function is maintained for the session.

And mysqli interface provides a wrapper for the LAST_INSERT_ID() function at the session level.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

As far as making a method/function available for a prepared statement, I've never used that.

I suspect that on the prepared statement, the `insert_id` function is really a wrapper/passthru to a function at the session (or link, as mysqli refers to it.)

If that's the case, that means that the call to `insert_id` needs to be made immediately following the execute of the prepared statement INSERT, before any other INSERT statement is executed.

(I'm not really sure about any of that. It's *possible* that the mysqli developers implemented code that automatically runs the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` statement immediately following the successful execution of a prepared statement INSERT, and cache that, before the execute call returns. Then, when the `insert_id` function is called, it returns the cached value. I don't really think that's the case. But it is *possible*.  If that is the case, I still wouldn't have my code rely on that behavior. I would want to get the LAST_INSERT_ID() immediately following the INSERT, before I ran any other statements on the MySQL session.